# Can I separate ALL HTTP headers with a comma? Even Authorization?

Tags: http, apache, rfc, rfc2616

I am reading through the HTTP 1.1 RFCs and I am not able to answer the following question.

We have this header:

```
Authorization: Basic Qmxvb21iZXJnOnRjbG1lU1JT, Basic
```

which is causing troubles because Rails 3 authorization parser incorrectly decodes the string because of the "," character. This is very uncommon I know, but we add this using this Apache httpd configuration:

```
RequestHeader append Authorization "Basic" early
```

The [Apache mod_header documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) says:

> The response header is appended to any existing header of the same
>   name. When a new value is merged onto an existing header it is
>   separated from the existing header with a comma. This is the HTTP
>   standard way of giving a header multiple values.

But I don't think it is correct for this Authorization header. The RFC definition does not allow this. But some headers permit comma-separated list. I am not sure if this is a general rule for all HTTP headers.

I am **looking for a paragraph in the HTTP 1.1 RFC** that prooves my idea this is not correct. I have already found something that is saying "this is valid only for headers that can be separated", but this is not a proof.

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present
>   in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header
>   field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST
>   be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
>   "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
>   message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
>   separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same
>   field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation
>   of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the
>   order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

It really does not make sense, but I am looking for a clear proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the text you quoted:

"Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]."

This is not the case for "Authorization".

Comment: Well I was not able to find anything else. Looks like this is it after 7 hours of sleep :-)